# Constrained optimization set up with at least one value constraint

Tags: optimization

I am working through setting up a optimization problem as:

```
min Ax
s.t. x ≥ 0
```

Where A is of size `1xp` and hence x has size `px1`.

How do I add a condition such that at least one of x has value `100`.

Comment: I am wondering if there would exist a minima if one of $A$ is negative, I don't think so! And if none of A is negative I would give 100 to the one of x which corresponds to least of A and rest all zero!

Answer (score 2):

You may write $$(x_1-100)(x_2-100)\cdots (x_p-100)=0$$if i get the question rightly. Also you may define $$y=x-100$$ and rewrite the optimization problem for sake of simplicity.

Comment: Very nice. .. thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope it helps you!

Comment: The first solution cant be represented in matrix form and second solution doesn't guarantee 100